# Install officewriter for two instances of reporting server on a single machine

Tags: officewriter

We have installed two instance of the MS report server (2012) on the same machine for two instances of the same application.

There are some reports that have created using OfficeWriter. For them to work, we need to install office writer.

When installing office writer, we can specify only one report server instance during the installation wizard (if we have multiple instances if RS). But I need to integrate office writer with both RS instances.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks you!
Wijitha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The installer will only setup one instance at a time as you noticed.

However you can do a manual install for the second instance.

Checkout the installation guides at http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/OW9/Installation

or jump straight to the 2012 installation information at http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/OW9/Installing+for+SSRS+2012